# How would I find this constant?

Tags: problem-solving, markov-chains, systems-of-equations, integral-equations

I have this equation, and I'm not sure how to solve for the constant $\nu$, since everything else is known:

$$\begin{equation}
a + \sqrt{a_i + 4 b_i \nu} + \sum^N_{j=1} (\sqrt{a_j + 4 b_j \nu}) p_{i,j}= 2\omega
\end{equation}$$

I merely need to extract $\nu$ and $p_{i,j}$ are transition probabilities for a Markov chain. $a,b,p$ and $\omega$ are all known.

Comment: I doubt this is possible in closed form; with even three terms of this type, Wolfram gives a horrifying mess.

Comment: can you even enter something like this in wolfram?

Comment: In general no, but I picked numbers to get an idea. Try, for instance, $\sqrt{1+4x}+\sqrt{1+2x}/2+\sqrt{1+3x}/2=10$. The result is a mess, although it does *technically* have a closed form. I suspect Wolfram is reducing the problem to the roots of a polynomial of degree 3, which means a closed form solution may simply not exist in some cases with $N \geq 4$.

Comment: so root finding is my best shot?

Comment: I think so, yeah. It should be pretty easy, assuming the $b$ are all nonnegative, your function is smooth and monotone in $\nu$, and it is not hard at all to find an interval where the solution must exist. In my example for instance, the solution is clearly in $[0,25]$.

Comment: maybe if i expressed it in vector form, does wolfram do that?

Comment: Wait, this equation holds with the *same* value of $\nu$ for each $i$? That sounds rather unusual.

Comment: it does, it comes as a constant of integration for the general form. Its not unusual, there's one equation and one unknown

Comment: I don't understand. Is there a separate equation for each $i$? Perhaps take $N=2$, choose values of the parameters, and write your equation explicitly.

Comment: That doesn't fully explain it, because you haven't told me the scope of the indices. Really, concrete numbers with a small $N$ would clear a lot up.

Comment: So, for two N, say we start with state 1. Then:

$\begin{equation}
a + \sqrt{a_1 + 4 b_1 \nu} + \sqrt{a_1 + 4 b_1 \nu} p_{1,1} + \sqrt{a_2 + 4 b_2 \nu} p_{1,2} = 2w
\end{equation}$

Comment: Does the same value of $\nu$ work when we start with state $2$?

Comment: no, it wont. but we assume we start from a state i. And there's only one possible value of $\nu$ given that we start from a state and calibrate then

Comment: There we go. Then yes, provided $b_i \geq 0$ you can run any root finding algorithm using the initial interval $[0,w^2/b_1]$. This should converge pretty quick.

Comment: perfect, thanks Ian. Sorry about my lack of clarity